# Generating millions of random integers to give as input to a Java program

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, terminal

I've wrote some sorting algorithms in Java, and verified their correctness for small inputs. Now, I wanted to check how they fare against each other as the number of elements that need sorting reach up to millions.

So I was looking for something along the steps:

1. Run the sorting algorithm
2. Ask the number of elements user wants to sort (I'd likely input > 1 million)
3. Give the input of entered size through random integer generation.

I was wondering how the 3rd step could be achieved, w/o having to rewrite the sorting algorithms themselves. I'm using LINUX terminal to run my code.

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far and what is your question?

Comment: I've written a script that can generate random integers for me. What I do not get is how I can give the output of this script as the input to the sorting algorithm scripts.

Comment: How can we suggest how to pass values from your script if we don't know anything about your code? Where are the implementations of your algorithms? Where's the script that generates your input?

Comment: Does this mean this script is not in Java? Why?

Comment: Here's what I'd do: get random numbers, one per line, from [here](https://www.random.org/integer-sets/)  and use `BufferedReader` or `LineNumberReader` to read as many lines as integers needed.

Comment: Kevin, did you end up solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly simple way chain together the output of a linux script to the input of a java program.  The following approach should work for you

```
echo N | ./createInput.sh | java -cp "/srcpath/" packagePath/YourInputToAlgorithm
```

Where:

1. N is the number of elements to sort
2. createInput.sh is the linux number generator (must accept $1 as number of elements)
3. YourInputToAlgorithm is the java code which uses a Scanner to read values then executes your sorting algorithm on the input

Here are very simple implementations to illustrate the approach:

Linux generator:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Read the number of elements 
read NUMBER_ELEMENTS
# Must echo it to Java program
echo $NUMBER_ELEMENTS
# This implementation just creates number 1..NUMBER_ELEMENTS in reverse order
until [  $NUMBER_ELEMENTS-lt 1 ]; do
    echo $NUMBER_ELEMENTS
    let NUMBER_ELEMENTS-=1
done
```

Java Code:

```
public class ReadStdIn {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberElements = s.nextInt();
    while (numberElements > 0) {
        input.add(s.nextInt());
        numberElements--;
    }
    s.close();
    Collections.sort(input);   // Here you would call your algorithm
    System.out.println(input);
}
}
```

An example:

```
echo 5 | ./createInput.sh | java -cp "/src/" stackoverflow/ReadStdIn
```

Creates the output as expected:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```